# Determine if an interval is contained in an infinite sum of multiples of other intervals

Tags: algorithm, math, intervals

I came across an interesting problem recently which I don't think I've seen posted here before:

Given a finite set of disjoint closed intervals I<sub>1</sub>, I<sub>2</sub>, ..., I<sub>n</sub>, construct the covering I = U (i<sub>1</sub> I<sub>1</sub> + i<sub>2</sub> I<sub>2</sub> + ... + i<sub>n</sub> I<sub>n</sub>) where the union is taken over all possible sequences (i<sub>1</sub>, ..., i<sub>n</sub>) of nonnegative integers. Here, the sum of two intervals is meant literally as the set of sums of elements from either set.

We may assume for simplicity that the endpoints of each I<sub>k</sub> are positive integers.

The problem is to determine, given another interval X = [a,b] (for some positive integers a,b), whether or not X is contained entirely within I or not.

Comment: What does the notation iI mean if i is a nonnegative integer and I is an interval?

Comment: It means that interval obtained from I by multiplying every element by i. In other words, if I = [a,b], then iI = [ia,ib].